# Creating a text file of list and then re-accessing the text file in some other program. Python

Tags: python

I am facing a parsing error I guess but I am not able to correct it.

I have a list of numbers in store=[0,3,4,5.....]
I want to save these numbers in a text file such that I am able to access this text file and use those numbers as integers only for my next program.
The text file should contain numbers like

```
0
3
4
5
```

But, when I try to use the code,

```
Type Error: Expected a Character buffer object.
```

The code which I am trying is:

```
output_file=open("bins.txt","w")
for r in range(0,len(store)):
    output=store[r]
    output_file.write(output)
output_file.close()
```

Please guide me on what should I change so that I can access these as integers only in next program and also tell me how can I use it in the next program.
Thank you

Comment: You need to convert integers to string upon writing to the file: `output_file.write(str(output))`

Comment: It would be better if you use `pickle` or `shelve` built-in library, faster and more convenient.

Comment: side note: you'll want to use a `with` block instead of the `output_file.close()` method at the end. like this: `with open("bins.txt","w"):`, followed by the rest. the file will automatically close when you are done (even if there are errors)- no need for the `close()` method.

Comment: Thank you, the output is coming now but it is in same line. I want one number to be in one line by using \n but I d'nt know how to add it. Can u pls tell me.

Comment: It is all about adding '\n' in write() method. Just check my answer below. It will work as you expected.

Answer (score 2):

I've written the below code based on your code. It will work now. The fix is: Python is expecting a character buffer whereas you are passing integer values. When you change the type to the expected type, that is using str(value), the TypeError will vanish away. That's it!

```
 output_file=open("bins.txt","w")
 for r in range(0,len(store)):
     output=store[r]
     output_file.write(str(output) + '\n')
 output_file.close()
```

Comment: `output_file.write("{}\n".format(output))` is more like it.

Comment: Superb @ozgur. Yours is the smarter way, Python way!

Comment: Thank you so much. That worked for me. :) God bless.

Answer (score 1):

Like so

```
store = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
with open('file.txt', 'w') as f:
    for num in store:
        f.write('%d\n' % num)

''' in other file '''

with open('file.txt') as f:
    nums = [int(line) for line in f]

for n in nums:
    print('%d' % n)
```

You can't write the integer values directly to the file. You need to convert them to strings. There are several ways to achieve this. You will see one in the other answer and yet another in its comments. I have shown another way.

To read the values back simply open the file and convert each line to `int`. The conversion ignores the newline present at the end of each line, so there is no need for `strip`.